# Why is the electric field zero outside this sphere?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, conductors

> The inside of a grounded spherical metal shell of radius $R$ is filled with a charge density $\rho$. Find the electric field outside the sphere.

The answer is zero, but I don't understand why. What is it about a grounded sphere that makes the electric field stop at the surface?

Comment: As you probably know, the field within the bulk of an ideal conductor is zero.  How do you suppose that comes to pass in the situation that you describe?

Comment: @garyp Wait my first question is this - how do you know the shell is a conductor?

Comment: The problem says "metal shell".   To make any progress you have to know something more about the metal.  Without further guidance we have little choice but to assume that it's an ideal conductor.

Comment: @garyp but if there is charge inside, then there must be an electric field inside, no?

Comment: There is no field within the bulk material of the conductor,  but there could be a field inside the shell.   Remember, this is a shell with a wall that has some thickness to it.   However, the question asks about the field *outside* the shell.   Since you know that the answer is zero, think about what Gauss's Law says *must* be the case.

Comment: So then it means that the total charge enclosed within an outer Gaussian surface must be zero. So that means that the inner charge is being negated by an induced surface charge of equal magnitude but opposite sign?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  A few details to fill in, but that's the main part of the argument.